# Script works for me but not the people I've shared the spreadsheet with

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, share

I've created a script. It works for me but not for the people I've shared my spreadsheet with. The script is designed to add a timestamp and insert a row when I edit a specific cell. The script is as follows: -

```
function onEdit(e) {

    var ss = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var sheet = ['LIVE!']
    if (ss.getName() !== 'LIVE!' || e.range.columnStart !== 6) return;
    if (e.range.columnStart == e.range.columnEnd && 
      e.range.rowStart == e.range.rowEnd &&
      e.range.rowStart == 5 && e.value)
     e.range.offset(0, -5).setValue(e.value ? new Date() : null); {
    e.source.getActiveSheet().insertRowBefore(5);
  }
}
```

I'm unsure of how to get it to work for the people I share the spreadsheet with (There are potentially hundreds going to use this within my organisation).

Do I need to authorise the script somehow for all users?

Unfortunately I'm unable to share the sheet as it contains sensitive information.

Comment: I've figured it out. Some of the sheets and ranges were protected. I've removed the protections and the script works for everyone :)

Comment: Please consider to post the solution that you found as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. Some of the sheets and ranges were protected. I've removed the protections and the script works for everyone.